# Elasticsearch filter document group by field

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, distinct

I have some documents:

```
{"name": "John", "district": 1},
{"name": "Mary", "district": 2},
{"name": "Nick", "district": 1},
{"name": "Bob", "district": 3},
{"name": "Kenny", "district": 1}
```

How can I filter/select distinct documents by district?

```
{"name": "John", "district": 1},
{"name": "Mary", "district": 2},
{"name": "Bob", "district": 3}
```

In SQL, I can use GROUP BY. I tried terms aggregation but it only returned count distinct.

```
"aggs": {
  "distinct": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "district",
      "size": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Thank for your help! :-)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If your ElasticSearch version is 1.3 or above, you could use a subaggregation of type [top_hits](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) which will give you (by default) the top three matching documents sorted on your query score (here, 1 as you use a match_all query).

You can set the `size` parameter to more than 3.

The following dataset and query :

```
POST /test/districts/
{"name": "John", "district": 1}

POST /test/districts/
{"name": "Mary", "district": 2}

POST /test/districts/
{"name": "Nick", "district": 1}

POST /test/districts/
{"name": "Bob", "district": 3}

POST test/districts/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs":{
    "by_district":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "district",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tops": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Will output the documents the way you want :

```
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "by_district": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 1,
               "key_as_string": "1",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "tops": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 2,
                     "max_score": 1,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "test",
                           "_type": "districts",
                           "_id": "XYHu4I-JQcOfLm3iWjTiOg",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "name": "John",
                              "district": 1
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "_index": "test",
                           "_type": "districts",
                           "_id": "5dul2XMTRC2IpV_tKRRltA",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "name": "Nick",
                              "district": 1
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": 2,
               "key_as_string": "2",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "tops": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 1,
                     "max_score": 1,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "test",
                           "_type": "districts",
                           "_id": "I-9Gd4OYSRuexhP1dCdQ-g",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "name": "Mary",
                              "district": 2
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": 3,
               "key_as_string": "3",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "tops": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 1,
                     "max_score": 1,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "test",
                           "_type": "districts",
                           "_id": "bti2y-OUT3q2mBNhhI3xeA",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "name": "Bob",
                              "district": 3
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, you save my life!!

Comment: Hey @ThomasC, any idea how to also filter records that are to be aggregated like this? I'm trying for half an hour already. Thanks !

Comment: Hi @lisak! You can't nest an aggregation under a top_hits, however, the opposite is possible. Try using a filter aggregation and nest a top_hits under. Or, you can filter results in the query section

Comment: @ThomasC can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764307/elasticsearch-get-customised-result-based-on-parameter

Comment: This works but if there are more than 500 unique districts, is there a way I could do pagination, where do i put in "from" keyword, the terms aggregation doesn't support it

Answer (score 2):

Elastic search does not provide distinct documents on value or group by unique value .
But there is work around for this you can do this if you are using java client or can convert it in your suitable language

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet();
SearchHits hits = response.getHits();

Iterator<SearchHit> iterator = hits.iterator();
Map<String, SearchHit> distinctObjects = new HashMap<String,SearchHit>();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    SearchHit searchHit = (SearchHit) iterator.next();
    Map<String, Object> source = searchHit.getSource();
    if(source.get("district") != null){
        distinctObjects.put(source.get("district").toString(),source);
    }

}
```

Comment: What if  you are using pagination? Are getting pages with 8 results, other with 10 and other with 7 if you get 10 results per page?

Comment: it is not workaround. it is own wheel rewrite. Are you going to read all the objects in your memory? what if there are millions of them?