# Elasticsearch apply search filter on aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have an elasticsearch (v2.3) backend storing ip addresses in multiple indices. The document type of an ip looks like this :

```
{
  "ip" : {
    "properties" : {
       "ip":         { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
       "categories": { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to group all ip documents by unique ip field to apply an operation with categories (and all other fields) of all records.

There is an easy way to go : aggregating all unique ip documents with the aggregation below and iterating over each result in my script making an other search query.

```
{
  'size': 0,
  'aggs': {
    'uniq': {
      'terms': { 'fields': 'ip', 'size': 0 }
    }
  }
}
```

But it is not very efficient. Is there a way to do this in one single search query ?

I've seen a workaround here [Elasticsearch filter document group by field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986538/elasticsearch-filter-document-group-by-field), with a top_hits aggregation :

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs":{
    "uniq":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "ip",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tops": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I can't have top_hits size to 0, which is what I want because I would like it to handle cases with the same ip in N different indices.

I've taken a look at pipeline aggregations but it does seem to be able to perform raw searches.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Quick question but why aren't you using the [IPv4 type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip.html) instead of string for mapping your IP addresses?

Comment: I also need to be able to store ipv4 networks, ipv6 and ipv6 networks