# Aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to apply group by clause on date field for elasticsearch query. This is my code.

```
SearchRequestBuilder  srb  = client
                .prepareSearch(ConstantsValue.indexName)
                .setTypes(ConstantsValue._Type)
                .addAggregation(

                        AggregationBuilders
                          .dateHistogram("aggs")
                          .field("DTCREATED")
                          .interval(Interval.MONTH)
                          .format("yyyy-MM-dd")
                          .preZone("+05:30")
                          .preZoneAdjustLargeInterval(true)
                          .minDocCount(1)       
                        )
                .setSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .setQuery(query);  

SearchResponse response =    srb
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setFetchSource(ConstantsValue.fieldList, null)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

But query does not return expected result.

Result displayed is as follows

```
Value  :{"DTCREATED":"2016-09-29T18:30:00.000Z"}
Key  :AVfdaeSC3n3Bn-RaoFgg
Value  :{"DTCREATED":"2016-09-29T18:30:00.000Z"}
Key  :AVfdaeSC3n3Bn-RaoFgl
Value  :{"DTCREATED":"2016-09-29T18:30:00.000Z"}
Key  :AVfdaeSC3n3Bn-RaoFgq
Value  :{"DTCREATED":"2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"}
Key  :AVfdaeSC3n3Bn-RaoFgv
Value  :{"DTCREATED":"2016-09-06T18:30:00.000Z"}
Key  :AVfdaeSC3n3Bn-RaoFg0
Value  :{"DTCREATED":"2016-09-22T18:30:00.000Z"}
Key  :AVfdaeSC3n3Bn-RaoFg5
Value  :{"DTCREATED":"2016-09-22T18:30:00.000Z"}
Key  :AVfdaeSC3n3Bn-RaoFhA
Value  :{"DTCREATED":"2016-09-12T18:30:00.000Z"}
Key  :AVfdaeSC3n3Bn-RaoFhF
```

I am new in elasticsearch and don't know what I am missing. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: how does your query look like?

Comment: I have query for SQL ----                                                                                      select distinct(SSTATUS),count(SSTATUS), TO_DATE (dtcreated, 'DD.MON.YYYY') 
from tableName WHERE SSTATUS LIKE 'CANCELLED'
group by
TO_DATE (dtcreated, 'DD.MON.YYYY') , sstatus order by SSTATUS

Comment: How're you querying it in java ? You're using the SQL query directly in your code?

Comment: Kibana generated query is also there but it's not working

Comment: no using SearchRequest class and passing Kibana query to its source field

Comment: Can you provide sample code so that I can figure out how to use term aggregation using http post

Comment: I've provided it below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `groupby` like clause in ES but then you could use the [Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) in order to group by the field you want. For example I'm using the post http request below in order to group using `userid` and get the count for each userid.

The search query would look like this:

http://localhost:9200/response_summary/_search

In the above, response_summary is the index. i'm trying do the search.

The body of the request can be something like this:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "query_string":{  
         "query":"api:\"smsmessaging\" AND operatorid:\"ROBI\""
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "total":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"userid"
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "grades_count":{  
               "value_count":{  
                  "script":"doc['userid'].value"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So you could mention the field you wanted to `groupby` within the `aggs` tag and get the count as a sample in the above. You could modify as you wish. Could have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986538/elasticsearch-filter-document-group-by-field) thread as well.