# elasticsearch: get customised result based on parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am exploring `elasticsearch`. I have some indexed documents like this

```
[
    {"assetName" :"book1","source":"Shelf1"},
    {"assetName" :"book2","source":"Shelf1"},
    {"assetName" :"book3","source":"Shelf1"},
    {"assetName" :"book11","source":"Shelf2"},
    {"assetName" :"book12","source":"Shelf2"},
    {"assetName" :"book13","source":"Shelf2"},
    {"assetName" :"book21","source":"Shelf3"},
    {"assetName" :"book22","source":"Shelf3"}
]
```

Now if I pass **book** as search parameter then it should return document based on source that is from  each **source** (Shelf1,shelf2,shelf3) first and after that other results. So the resulted json will be

```
[
    {"assetName" :"book1","source":"Shelf1"},
    {"assetName" :"book11","source":"Shelf2"},
    {"assetName" :"book21","source":"Shelf3"},
    {"assetName" :"book2","source":"Shelf1"},
    {"assetName" :"book3","source":"Shelf1"},
    {"assetName" :"book12","source":"Shelf2"},
    {"assetName" :"book13","source":"Shelf2"},
    {"assetName" :"book22","source":"Shelf3"}
]
```

Is it possible in `elasticsearch`?

Comment: What have you tried? And what are the other documents samples?

Comment: same kind of documents. I am trying sorting but not working  even not able to figure out :(